# Audio recorder restarting

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I've create Audio recorder. When rotating my device the audio will be automatically saved. How can I avoid this ? I'm using Android 4.1.1 on device.

```
   private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;
     private static final String LOG_TAG = "MediaAudioCapture";
     ImageButton button_audio_button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.audio_button);
      button_audio_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View record_button) {
      ImageButton audio_button = (ImageButton) record_button;
      if (!started_note_recording) {
        if (!started_recording) {
          startRecording();
          audio_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.audio_red);
         } else {
         stopRecording();
         audio_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.audio);
         }
        }
      }
     });
    private void startRecording() {
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(output.getAbsolutePath());
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    ImageButton button_audio_button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.audio_button);
    button_audio_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.audio);
    }
   }
  });
    try {
      mRecorder.prepare();
     } catch (IOException e) {
   Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
   }
  mRecorder.start();
  stopWatch.start();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you rotate, activity will be reload. You can fix the orientation to portrait or you have to change your logic to retain the state on rotation.

Comment: Thanks you are Right know my activity restarting. That is exactly my problem. But i want my activity in both landscape and portrait . there is anyway to do this?

Comment: i have not tried it but for playing a video or audio we can try to save the position of it and on orientation change continue it from there but in your case you are recording it. you will have to pass the object of the recorder and then retreive it oncreate of the activity and continue it. i am not sure of it because when you rotate the activity is destroyed and created again so onstop you need to store the object and oncreate need to retreive it and continue. if i get more info on this i will update you with it

Comment: Yes, do you know how to get the Recording position. and how can i set it again without break ..